# Convert a cv::Mat to a pangolin::Image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an application that takes in `pangolin::Image` format rgbd images. I would like to send in a `cv::Mat`. How can I convert a cv::Mat to a pangolin::Image?

(pangolin:  https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin)

Image header:

https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/blob/master/include/pangolin/image/image.h

currently the format is:

```
pangolin::ManagedImage<unsigned short> firstData(640, 480);

    pangolin::Image<unsigned short> firstRaw(firstData.w, firstData.h, firstData.pitch, (unsigned short*)firstData.ptr);
```

where `firstRaw` is then sent through the application.

If I now have:

`cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(filepath,0);`

What is the conversion from `frame` to `firstRaw`?

I start like this:

```
int loadDepthFromMat(cv::Mat filepath, pangolin::Image<unsigned short> & depth)
{
    int width = filepath.cols;
    int height = filepath.rows;

    pangolin::ManagedImage<unsigned short> depthRaw(width, height);

    pangolin::Image<unsigned short> depthRaw16((unsigned short*)depthRaw.ptr, depthRaw.w, depthRaw.h, depthRaw.w * sizeof(unsigned short));


//copy data 

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming the pangolin::Image is on host/cpu memory, just use memcpy() on the data pointers after making sure the pangolin Image has been allocated. Just make sure to convert the OpenCV image to the unsigned short format first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please give me an example if you have a moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming you have converted your cv::Mat to unsigned short format with the correct pitch (or channels, in OpenCV), you just use memcpy.

(I've renamed your cv::Mat from filepath to mat (why is it called filepath?)):

```
memcpy((void*)depthRaw16.begin(), (void*)mat.data, mat.total() * mat.elemSize());
```

Again, be **sure** your pangolin image has identical dimensions and be **sure** the cv::Mat is converted to unsigned short.

Comment: Thank you! So as long as I set up the `Image` with : `int width = mat.cols;
 int height = mat.rows;

 pangolin::ManagedImage<unsigned short> depthRaw(width, height);`, i should be fine? Now I just need to find the UShort conversion... Thanks again

Comment: .. adding `int channels = mat.channels();` and `pangolin::Image<unsigned short> firstRaw(width,height,channels, (unsigned short*)firstData.ptr);`

Comment: You'll want cv::Mat::convertTo. So instantiate a new cv::Mat (e.g., mat_ushort), and do mat.convertTo(mat_ushort, CV_16UC1); (for grayscale) or mat.convertTo(mat_ushort, CV_16UC3); (for RGB) or CV_16UC4 if you have RGBA. Then use that new cv::Mat for the memcpy operation. Using convertTo will set the channels() property, setting it manually will do nothing.

Comment: Works great! thank you very much for your time. (To anyone else doing this, you need to convert the Mat type BEFORE you read the mat.channels() into a var)